# intersection observer multiple animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, intersection-observer

I want to achieve different animation for many elements on scroll, so instead of using window.scroll i'm using intersection observer api, but i want to know if my approach is effective and won't cause performance drop, basically what i did is make a single function to hold the entire animation of the website and check if the target has specific class then do something like so :

```
const one = document.querySelector('.one')
const two = document.querySelector('.two')
const three = document.querySelector('.three')

function animation (entires) {
    entires.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting) {
            if(entry.target.classList.contains('text')) {
               entry.target.style.transform = 'translateY(0)'
            }
            if(entry.target.classList.contains('one')) {
               entry.target.style.transform = 'translateX(100px)'
            }
            if(entry.target.classList.contains('two')) {
               entry.target.style.transform = 'translateY(0)'
            }
            if(entry.target.classList.contains('three')) {
               entry.target.style.transform = 'skew(10deg)'
            }
        }
    })
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(animation)
```

i'm not experienced enough but i feel like it's spaghetti code and not efficient and how can i observe multiple elements ? do i have to repeat observer.observe for each element i want to observe ?

Comment: You can just toggle a class for the element that comes into view and handle the actual logic of the styling in the CSS.

Comment: @cloned good suggestion but do you think my approach overall is decent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Intersection Observer API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) helps determine if a specific element is visible in a viewport and animations are a perfect use case for this API, so no performance drop there, on the contrary, it has a smoother performance than `window.scroll`. But in small examples like these it's not really noticeable.

You can also use it for:

- Image lazy loading
- Infinite scroll
- Launching actions based on viewport visibility

https://jsfiddle.net/v6hyqtoa/

```js
const one = document.querySelector('.one')
const two = document.querySelector('.two')
const three = document.querySelector('.three')

const divs = [one, two, three];

function animation(entires) {
  entires.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      if (entry.target.classList.contains('one')) {
        entry.target.style.transform = 'translateX(100px)'
      }
      if (entry.target.classList.contains('two')) {
        entry.target.style.transform = 'translateY(0)'
      }
      if (entry.target.classList.contains('three')) {
        entry.target.style.transform = 'skew(10deg)'
      }
    }
  })
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(animation)
divs.forEach((div) => observer.observe(div));
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <p>
    ------------------------------- <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <br/> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
    quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
    modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
    qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    <br/> At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
    assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut
    aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
    <br/>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <p>
    ------------------------------- <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <br/> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
    quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
    modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
    qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    <br/> At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
    assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut
    aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
    <br/>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="three">
  <p>
    ------------------------------- <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <br/> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
    quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
    modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
    qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    <br/> At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
    assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut
    aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </p>
</div>
```

<sup>More reading : [Animate on scroll with intersection observer](https://medium.com/@mciastek/animate-on-scroll-with-intersection-observer-ea744cddb876)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much islam, i really appreciate that a lot
1 more question if you don't mind, do you think my approach overall is decent ? like would you do something like that in production ?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't. If you do that you'd have to keep track of every class you add and always remember to add its JS in your observer. Unless you're making a static page, I wouldn't recommend it.